# how to load external xml using air application for flash programmer?

Tags: flash, air

i have faced this problem couple of days ago, while trying to import an external xml file into an AIR application.

```
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
 var url:String = "http://willperone.net/rss.php";
 var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
 ldr.load(urlReq);
 ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , function(e) {
    trace('Wow, completed ...');
 });
 ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e) {
    trace('IO_ERROR');
 });
```

and always the IO_ERROR shows up.
may i do it wrong or something needs a little of configuration, so please help

Comment: Nothing obvious is jumping out at me. Can you try tracing the error message itself and post what it says? trace('IO_Error: '+e);

Comment: thank you,
the error msg that shows up 

IO_ERROR[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: http://willperone.net/rss.php" errorID=2035]

note that i tried to change the url and using URLLoader and the same error still shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, 
i found where the problem is :
i didn't specify the type of the received content,
it solved when i used

```
request.contentType = "text/xml";
```

so the code will look like this :

```
function getData(onComplete) {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://...");
    request.contentType = "text/xml";
    request.data = "";
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE ,function(e) { xmlParser(e); onComplete(e); } );
    try
    {
        mainData.splice(0,mainData.length);
        loader.load(request);
        return true;
    }
    catch (e){
        return false;
    }
}


function xmlParser(e) {
    var xml:XML = new XML(URLLoader(e.target).data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IOErrorEvent` is telling you that it can't load the resource you are trying to load. Is there anything actually at http://willperone.net/rss.php. Perhaps an XML or PHP parse error? I also just noticed you are using `Loader` to try to load text content. The class you want to use to load XML (or text, json, binary, etc.) is [`URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html). `Loader` is a `DisplayObject` subclass mostly for loading swfs, images, and visual assets into the display list. This is the likely culprit.

Comment: thank you,
actually i tried using the URLLoader with diffrent url and the same error still shows up and here is some details 

IO_ERROR[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: http://willperone.net/rss.php" errorID=2035]

please note am testing the code by creating a new AIR project using flash cs4, i don't why it shows up ...

Comment: If you can navigate to the URL in your browser, then I'd think it's maybe some kind of php header() issue. Check that your resource is valid XML to start.